# UIDocumentPickerExtensionViewController validTypes

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an app with a document provider extension and would like to filter the view presented to a user based on the UTIs passed by the consuming application. The validTypes member of UIDocumentPickerExtensionViewController appears to be intended to serve this purpose but it's nil when the extension is invoked. Is there some step the caller or extension must take to ensure this value is populated? The caller is passing a list of UTIs to the initWithDocumentTypes method on UIDocumentPickerViewController.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIDocumentPickerExtensionViewController validTypes is always nil](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088573/uidocumentpickerextensionviewcontroller-validtypes-is-always-nil)

Answer (score 0):

[UIDocumentPickerExtensionViewController validTypes is always nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088573/uidocumentpickerextensionviewcontroller-validtypes-is-always-nil) answers this. Basically, validTypes is nil in viewDidLoad but there are other interfaces where it can be read.